# Can I "Ref" and "GetAtt" an implicit defined API in a AWS SAM template?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-serverless

I have a AWS Serverless Application Model (SAM) template in which I define an API implicit by defining events at the Functions (as described [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/de_de/lambda/latest/dg/serverless_app.html)).

Now I want to use the API Gateway in a CloudFront Distribution. For this I normally would use Ref and Fn::GetAtt to get the attributes of the API. But since it is not explicitly defined, I do not know what to "Ref".

Is there a way? or do I have to define the API explicitly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An implicit API is given the name `ServerlessRestApi`. I haven't yet tried to use `!Ref` or `!GetAtt` with the implicit API resource, but I would assume that it would be possible as it works with other generated resources.

Here is a link to the GitHub docs that discuss the implicit API resources: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/docs/internals/generated_resources.rst#api